# SAMBA: how to mount resource in oracle virtualbox from windows8

Tags: debian, samba, shared-directory

I set up a shared folder on my debian devbox on oracle virtualbox:

```
[web]
    path = /var/www/web
    available = yes
    valid users = my_name
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    public = yes
    writable = yes
```

I run testparm and everything is ok, but I can't mount it from my win8.1, using

```
\\<ip_address>\web
```

any idea from how to start to debug this? thanks

p.s.: I tried guest addiction shared folders and it works, but it is really too slow...

Comment: Does Windows see the share if you simply go to `\\<ip_address>`?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `Bridged Adapter` in network settings. From my experience, I was never able to access samba on the host in `NAT` mode.

Try also these options:

```
[global]
   map to guest = bad user
...

[web]
...
   guest ok = yes
   force user = my_name
```

And restart `samba` service.

Comment: yes I tried already, same result :(. maybe something with iptables to check?

Comment: I added some options to try.

Comment: ok tried but sameresult. looks like windows is unable to conect to my devbox, maybe some network problem rather then configuration, I think